# How to get a <input> id number into a var (Math)

Tags: javascript, html

I got a input number into a var. I subtracted it to a number.
Thank you vicodin for helping me! I fixed it and it works! (I changed names for my program)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p></p>

    <span><input type="number" id="guess1"><p id="g1s"></p></span>
    <input type="button" onclick="Calculate()" value="Calculate">

    <script>
function Calculate() {
    var GuessCon1 = document.getElementById("guess1").value;
    var GuessCon1sub = GuessCon1 - 500;
    document.getElementById("g1s").innerHTML = GuessCon1sub;
}
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's clear that you're struggling with some of the basics of JavaScript and the DOM. Unfortunately that will make it hard to answer this question for you in a way that would deeply explain the parts that you're missing. I recommend that you spend some time with some beginner JavaScript tutorials and potentially JavaScript documentation before continuing here on SO. [The JS tag wiki has a variety of good resources for getting started](/tags/javascript/info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assigned a string `"numb1"` to variable `g`. If you want to get the value of the input, you need to find that element (e.g. with `document.geElementById` method) and take a value from it.

Also, you want to trigger calculation, for example by a button click. I added a code in a snippet, you can run it and play around with it to get the idea.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("substract")

button.onclick = function() {
  var g = document.getElementById("numb1").value
  var a = 578;
  var x = g - a;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numb1">
<input type="submit" id="substract">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Related links:

[Input Text value Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

[onclick event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Comment: Please use type casting if you are using <input type='text' id="numb1">. eg var g= Number(document.getElementById("numb1").value)

Comment: @ShaileshDwivedi  input has a type of `number`